# Delphi XE icons

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I just installed Delphi XE and a few of the 3rd party components I use and some of the Component Icons are the default Delphi Icon.

I have tried the -nocache option on the IDE and that fixed most but not all.

anyone know why some are still displaying the default icon?

Comment: Are you sure the propper dcr files where there when you compiled the package(s) containing the 3rd. party components?  The problem may be there's no other _icon_ to show in the palette.

Comment: I've seen this happen when the package in question stores separate .RES files for component icons, in a different folder to the package .dproj file.
I resolve this either by relocating those .RES files, or adding their location to Delphi's search paths.

This may not apply in your particular case, but it's worth checking to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your components installation try to delete all entries in the following registry keys and restart your IDE twice. Twice because the first time cache entries are created but not used yet.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\Package Cache
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\8.0\Palette\Cache
```

According to your comment below it might have something to do with [this issue](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=78040).

Comment: It didn't help.  I removed the -nocache then deleted the 2 keys then restarted the ide twice and it was even worse, most 3rd party icons were the default, then I put the -nocache back in and I am back where I started, most are ok but a few are still the default.